# connecting data values to checkbox and set them to checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to get the *correct* checkboxes to be checked based on values that are being fetched from the database. So in my C# code I have a function that fetched data, and in my index I receive these. Here's the JavaScript/jQuery function where I get the data:

```
$.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: '@Url.Action("getRequestType", "Garage")?garageId=' + garageId,
                   dataType: 'JSON',
                   data: {
                       garageId: garageId
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    Values = data;
                    console.log(garageId, data);

                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        console.log("Has values: " + data);
                    }
                    else if (data.length <= 0) {
                        console.log("Has no values");
                    }
                }
            });
```

When using `console.log` I can see the values, so for example it could be:  `garageId: 4`, "`Has values: 4, 5, 8`". Now I would like these values to be connected to these checkboxes:

```
       @foreach (var items in Model)
        {
            <style>
                .ab {
                    margin-right: 8px;
                }
            </style>

            <div style=" width: 40%; display: block; float: right; margin-right: 10%; margin-top: 10%;">
                <h4>Choose request types for garage:</h4><br />
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class="rowa">
                        <label class="ab">Claim</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbclass" name="@items.Claim" id="Claim" placeholder="Claim" value="1" /> <!-- values for request type -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class="rowa">
                        <label class="ab">Scheduled Service</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbclass" name="@items.ScheduledService" id="ScheduledService" placeholder="Scheduled" value="2" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class="rowa">
                        <label class="ab">Tires</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbclass" name="@items.Tires" id="Tires" placeholder="Tires" value="3" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class="rowa">
                        <label class="ab">Rent Replacement Car</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbclass" name="@items.RentRepalcementCar" id="RentRepalcementCar" placeholder="Tires" value="4" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class="rowa">
                        <label class="ab">Other Work</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbclass" name="@items.OtherWork" id="OtherWork" placeholder="Tires" value="5" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class="rowa">
                        <label class="ab">Insurance</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbclass" name="@items.Insurance" id="Insurance" placeholder="Tires" value="6" />
                    </div>
                </div><br />
            </div>
        }
```

I've tried code similar to:

```
for (i = 0; i < Values.length; i++) {
                if (Values == 1) {
                    $("#Claim").prop("checked", true);
                }
                if (Values == 2) {
                    $("#ScheduledService").prop("checked", true);
                }
                if (Values == 3) { 
                    $("#Tires").prop("checked", true);
                }
                if (Values == 4) {
                    $("#RentRepalcementCar").prop("checked", true);
                }
                if (Values == 5) {
                    $("#OtherWork").prop("checked", true);
                }
                if (Values == 6) {
                    $("#Insurance").prop("checked", true);
                }
                return Values;
```

And:

```
 $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: '@Url.Action("getRequestType", "Garage")?garageId=' + garageId,
                   dataType: 'JSON',
                   data: {
                       garageId: garageId
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    Values = data;
                    console.log(garageId, data);

                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        //console.log("Has values: " + data);

                        if (data == 1) {
                            $("#Claim").prop("checked", true);
                        }
                        if (data == 2) {
                            $("#ScheduledService").prop("checked", true);
                        }
                        if (data == 3) {
                            $("#Tires").prop("checked", true);
                        }
                        if (data == 4) {
                            $("#RentRepalcementCar").prop("checked", true);
                        }
                        if (data == 5) {
                            $("#OtherWork").prop("checked", true);
                        }
                        if (data == 6) {
                            $("#Insurance").prop("checked", true);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (data.length <= 0) {
                        console.log("Has no values");
                    }
                }
            });
```

But, I hasn't had any success. The last method makes it possible to check boxes where `garageid` has **one** value (so basically one checkbox can be checked). Would much appreciate any help with this, if someone has any suggestions!

Comment: what is relation between `Values` from C# code and checkboxes `Id`. for example how do you know values of `Insurance` in database?

Comment: Instead of checking for `Values == 1` shouldn't you use `Values[i] == 1`? I would also suggest you refactor the code to not use if/else if trees. Instead have a dictionary or array of some sort where you map value to the element id.

Comment: @PeterKrebs you are very right, the [i] fixed it, thank you so much!! And you're right again the if/else isn't a great solution.. but thanks, if you wan't to post it as an answer i can accept it :)

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi, I simply use a select statement where I get the values based on the garageId!

Comment: Note `Values` is array so you need to use `Values [i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `Values` is array and you need to use `[i]` for it:

```
for (i = 0; i < Values.length; i++) {
    if (Values[i] == 1) {
        $("#Claim").prop("checked", true);
    }
    else if (Values[i] == 2) {
        $("#ScheduledService").prop("checked", true);
    }
....
```

Also you can use `switch case` too that is better option:

```
for (i = 0; i < Values.length; i++) {
    switch (Values[i]) {
        case 1:
            $("#Claim").prop("checked", true);
            break;
        case 2:
            $("#ScheduledService").prop("checked", true);
            break;
        ....
        default:
            console.log("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you!!! and that is true i'll try switch case instead